# How to get grid-only css file from bulma

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I am trying to use bulma framework, but I only need the grid part, sadly it's all in sass and I don't know how to get only the css part.

The repo is here https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/tree/master/sass/grid and I am assuming the grid is named `columns.sass`

If I downloaded bulma via npm as

```
npm install bulma
```

I already have get/sass installed. How can I get the grid part in css only?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `node-sass` to build the CSS version of the column (grid) you are referring to.

Use `npm` to download the `bulma` package. Then create a separate file that imports the `mixins.sass` and `column.sass` files. Finally, run `node-sass` to get you shiny new CSS file.

**grid.sass**

```
@import "utilities/mixins.sass"
@import "grid/columns.sass"
```

**Command-line**

`node-sass grid.sass grid.css`

Comment: This is the most clear answer I have received sofar, but I have just one question. Do you know where I should `grid.sass`?  So far this is what my dir looks like http://nyanimg.com/i/V0z8wdJg.png

Comment: Also, I get this error eventhough I am doing as your answer `[root@foobar bulma]# sass grid.sass output.css
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: utilities/mixins.sass.
        on line 1 of grid.sass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
`

Comment: The paths to the mixins and columns files will be relative to where your grid.sass file is located. Based on your image, navigate your terminal to the sass folder `assets/bulma/sass`. This is where you'll create your `grid.sass` file, run the `node-sass` command, and the paths I used should work.

Comment: I also noticed you're using the ruby sass gem, I'm not familiar with it and I answered your other question regarding its usage. You may want to consider node-sass, I found it to be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

As of version **0.7.1**, the way to compile just the Grid Column system is this:

Prerequisites: you need to have `node-sass` installed: `npm install -g node-sass`

1. Download or `git clone` the repo

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:jgthms/bulma.git
   cd bulma
   ```
2. Create a file `grid.sass` and add the following lines:

   ```
   @import "sass/utilities/_all"
   @import "sass/grid/columns"
   ```
3. Compile

   ```
   node-sass grid.sass grid.css
   ```

Answer (score 0):

An updated answer for `bulma > 0.4`,
you need to import `variables.sass` too

```
 @import "utilities/variables.sass"
 @import "utilities/mixins.sass"
 @import "grid/columns.sass"
```